# @Inject Warning Eclipse JBoss DS; injecting interface - no concrete class

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I'm using Spring 4.2.4 and MyFaces 2.2.9, Java 1.8.

I've created a Factory Pattern following this example; [Spring: implementing the Factory pattern](http://kh-yiu.blogspot.in/2013/04/spring-implementing-factory-pattern.html)

We have the **Interface**;

```
package com.jsf2.strategy;

public interface PrintStrategyFactory {         
    IPrintStrategy getStrategy(String strategyName); 
}
```

And in **applicationContext.xml**;

```
<bean id="printStrategyFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="com.jsf2.strategy.PrintStrategyFactory" />
</bean>

<alias name="A4Portrait" alias="A4P" />
<alias name="A4Landscape" alias="A4L" />
<alias name="A5Portrait" alias="A5P" />
<alias name="A5Landscape" alias="A5L" />
<alias name="A4Portrait" alias="DEFAULT" />
```

So there is **no concrete class** of PrintStrategyFactory, only the Interface.

I'm trying to use CDI syntax to inject the interface;

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class TestBean {

@Inject  // I get warning here
@Autowired // NO WARNING
private PrintStrategyFactory printStrategyFactory;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
. . . . . .
```

The @Autowired; *displays no warning*.

Using @Inject displays;

> No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]

At run-time, both ways work but I'm attempting to use CDI syntax.

If I add a Concrete class implementing the interface, the warning goes away.

Should I just suppress the warning or is there an alternative resolution?